# Picture-in-picture feature for WebRTC

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, webrtc, picture-in-picture

Apple [introduced](https://youtu.be/8XcYBu16T-g?t=381) *picture-in-picture* feature for iOS starting version 14.0 while it was available for iPadOS earlier. The feature works fine when using  `AVFoundation` API. For example,

```swift
import AVFoundation

func viewDidLoad() {
    let playerController = AVPlayerViewController()
    playerController.allowsPictureInPicturePlayback = true
}
```

What I am looking for is that if there are any solutions/APIs to implement picture-in-picture for **WebRTC** video streams in iOS and iPadOS, in particular, for `RTCVideoRenderer`.

Comment: Hi~Have you come up with any solutions?

Comment: Nope, I gave up on this approach.